# Locking row that is being currently inserted to avoid race conditions when reading same

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking

I have a system in which I'll dispatch events as part of transactions when inserting rows into the database.

This is to ensure that events only ever get dispatched for a successful insert, and that inserts are rolled back incase event dispatching fails.

Problem is that I'm seeing a race condition when dispatching an event after a successful insert. Sometimes the corresponding event listeners will receive the event, before the transaction has been committed, which will result in the row not being available at this time

Want I want to achieve is when inserting row A, any processes trying to read row A must wait until row A's transaction has been committed

Is this a sound approach and how is it best achieved?

For two processes **A** and **B**

**How it currently works**

1. A Start transaction
2. A Attempt insert
3. A dispatch event
4. B Receives event and attempts to read the inserted row
5. B Exception is raised as record is not visible yet
6. A commits transaction

**How I'd want it to work**

1. A Start transaction
2. A Attempt insert
3. A dispatch event
4. B Receives event and attempts to read the inserted row
5. B The row is currently locked by transaction so it waits until released
6. A commits transaction
7. B Lock is released and newly inserted row is returned

Comment: Your description is confusing. On the one hand, you say that events get dispatched only "for a successful insert". On the other hand, you say that inserts are rolled back when a dispatch fails. But the usual understanding of  *successful insert* means the transaction is committed. You can't roll back a committed transaction. Edit your question, and clarify the *actual* sequence of events.

Comment: *". . . any processes trying to read row A must wait until row A's transaction has been committed "* In a SQL database like PostgreSQL, this has to do with [transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html). PostgreSQL uses "Read Committed" isolation by default, but this is a per-transaction setting--every transaction can choose a different isolation level.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added some examples to hopefully clear it up

Comment: I read your edits. Is there a *compelling* reason for "A" to dispatch an event before "A" commits? That doesn't make sense to me. A commit can fail for a lot of reasons. Committing, *then* dispatching seems to make more sense.

Comment: I want the system to be durable. ie if the event dispatching fails, then to ensure the system does not end in an inconsistent state, I roll back the transaction

Comment: Your design *requires* an inconsistent state to start with. You want to dispatch an event that relies on an uncommitted row. Uncommitted row = inconsistent state here.

Comment: I see, is there any other way to accomplish this then?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question *and* the comments, I think the main issue here is that you want "A" to dispatch an event based on the content of an uncommitted row, and you want "B" to read and act on that uncommitted row. But in relational theory and in SQL databases, you don't know whether a commit will succeed. A commit can fail for lots of reasons--not only because some constraint fails, but because of things like insufficient permissions or disk space.

To borrow words from one of your comments, the dbms manages a database's transition from one consistent state to another. Uncommitted rows aren't known to be part of a consistent database state.  Only successfully *committed* rows are part of a consistent database state.

So I think, in general, you need "A" to commit before "B" tries to read the new row. And I think this is true even if you switch to a dbms that supports the "read uncommitted" transaction isolation level. (PostgreSQL does not, at least not in the way you might think.)

That means "B" will be responsible for deleting the new row (or for telling "A" to delete it) if "dispatching" fails. Neither "A" nor "B" can roll back a committed transaction.

It might make more sense for another process, "C", to oversee the actions of both "A" and "B".